# Is it possible to create two (or more) ASCX files with only one code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, ascx

My current situation:

I have a user control A.ascx with code behind A.ascx.cs and B.ascx with code behind B.ascx.cs.
Both code behind files contain similar code. Now I want to create only one CS file e.g. C.cs
which can be used by A.ascx and B.ascx.

Of course, C.cs must be able to access controls by ID which were used inside A.ascx and B.ascx.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes u can create a class file separely in App_Code folder "c.Cs" and move similar code to c.Cs and make use of it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can create single class and use it from both code behing classes. You can pass user control to that class and access controls by ID.

Any if you wont typed access to controls do something like this :

common class and interface that defines child controls that are on both user controls, and here you can access child controls :

```
  /// <summary>
  /// common controls
  /// </summary>
  public interface ICommonUserControl
  {
    TextBox TextBox1 { get; }
    Label Label1 { get; }
  }

  public class CommonCode
  {
    private ICommonUserControl commonUC;
    public CommonCode(ICommonUserControl uc)
    {
      this.commonUC = uc;
    }

    public void CommonWork()
    {
      this.commonUC.TextBox1.Text = "SomeText";
      this.commonUC.Label1.Text = "Other Text";
    }
  }
```

and then on all User controls you must implement the ICommonUserControl interface, something like this :

```
  public partial class UC1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, ICommonUserControl
  {
    public TextBox TextBox1 { get { return this.Uc1TextBox1; } }
    public Label Label1 { get { return this.Uc1Label1; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
```

And at the end here is the example of usage  :

```
  Control uc1 = this.LoadControl("UC1.ascx");
  this.phParent1.Controls.Add(uc1);
  Control uc2 = this.LoadControl("UC2.ascx");
  this.phParent2.Controls.Add(uc2);

  CommonCode cc1 = new CommonCode(uc1 as ICommonUserControl);
  cc1.CommonWork();
  CommonCode cc2 = new CommonCode(uc2 as ICommonUserControl);
  cc2.CommonWork();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, is there sth what I have to consider while integrating/registering this inside my ASCX files?

Comment: not sure I understand what you ask, you have to define your version of ICommonUserControl interface with common controls that you wont to access from common code, and of course implement that interface on all user controls

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really recommended as each ascx will come coupled with a designer.cs to reference the controls (if writing a web application) and C.cs may not be coupled with the same designer file as the one being referenced from the ascx.

My advice, create an abstract class (derived from UserControl) and have both user controls derive from that class, then just keep the common code in the abstract class passing in bespoke controls where required.